# Why do we use empty parentheses here in python reference to book data science from scratch?

Tags: python-3.x

Why do we use empty parentheses here in python?

My code is reference to book Data Science from scratch.

for user in users:
    user["friend"]=[]

In the above code Users is a list in which there are some dictionaries.

Answer (score 1):

That means you want to create a list with no value inside.
it is equivalent to `user["friend"] = list()`